# What's the name of this iterative method for approximating nth roots?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, roots, radicals, fixed-point-theorems

I came across this method for approximating n-th roots in an arithmetic book from 1843. I would like to know what iterative method is being used to perform the approximation, and if there is an example in modern notation.

[iterative method for approximating nth roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P88pv.png)

Second part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4W9P.jpg

Comment: Look's to just be Newton's method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book is that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Arithmetic 17th ed. by John Bonnycastle, corrected and improved by John Rowbotham, F.R.A.S.

Answer (score 4):

This is Halley's method with cubic order of convergence. It is the Newton method for the equation
$$
g(x)=x^{(n+1)/2}-ax^{-(n-1)/2}
$$
which can be obtained from the usual equation $f(x)=x^n-a$ by applying "flattening at the root", modifying $f$ by a factor so that $g''(r)=0$, which turns out to be dividing $f(x)$ by $\sqrt{|f'(x)|}$. Noting that constant factors can be omitted, this results here in a division by $x^{(n-1)/2}$.

Then
$$
x-\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}=x-\frac{x^{(n+1)/2}-ax^{-(n-1)/2}}{\frac{n+1}{2}\,x^{(n-1)/2}+a\frac{n-1}{2}x^{-(n+1)/2}}
\\~\\
=\frac{x((n+1)x^n+(n-1)a)-2x(x^n-a)}{(n+1)x^n+(n-1)a}
\\~\\
=x\frac{(n-1)x^n+(n+1)a}{(n+1)x^n+(n-1)a}
$$

Comment: So in order to approximate a fifth root I could do: https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?\sqrt[5]{a}=x\frac{4x^{5}&plus;6a}{6x^{5}&plus;4a}

Comment: If you see that formula as function in $x$, then its graph will be horizontal and tangent to third order at $x=\sqrt[5]a$. You will not get the root in one step, each iteration improves the approximation.